# why "moment('Tue Mar 31 2020').utc().format()" returns different result in different time zone?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Timezone: (UTC-06:00) Central America

```
> moment('Tue Mar 31 2020').utc().format()
"2020-03-31T06:00:00Z"
```

Timezone: (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi*

```
> moment('Tue Mar 31 2020').utc().format()
"2020-03-30T18:30:00Z"
```

Comment: Your images don't match the code or output in the question at all. Also, the two bits of code in the question are identical.

Comment: Because the initial string is interpreted naïvely, to the start of the specified day in local time, *then* converted to UTC.

Comment: There's fundamentally no correct answer what exact second of which hour "Tue Mar 31 2020" *should* resolve to in the first place…

Comment: The other thing you should notice in your browser console is the warning from `moment` telling you not to do that. See [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). In any *vaguely* up-to-date version of Moment, you're getting *"Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info."*

Comment: As time elapsed, output may vary but the point is why moment returns different output in different time zone.

Comment: *Because* they're different time zones. Why would it return the same output in different time zones?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Why did you remove the OP's images? They included them, presumably for some reason. Until/unless they come back and explain adequately what they're asking, it doesn't seem right to just remove them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they didn't seem to add anything and were screenshots of code; the title asks about moment's behaviour, which they didn't show, and there are already real code snippets illustrating that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Right, but again, the OP included them, I can't see removing them, it directly conflicts with the author's clear intent. VIPIN KUMAR - Why did you include seemingly unrelated screenshots in your question?

Answer (score 2):

`moment('Tue Mar 31 2020')` this bit means "Where I am, what timestamp is this human date representation". This value depends on the local timezone as `Tue Mar 31 2020` is a different instant in time depending on where you are.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948477/why-momenttue-mar-31-2020-utc-format-returns-different-result-in-diffe#comment107829452_60948477), this seems to be the answer to what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because you are telling moment to convert your date to UTC, then to format it. If you want to set a UTC date the syntax should be:

```
moment.utc([2020, 2, 31]).format();
```

Please note that:

months are 0 indexed, ranging from 0-11

days are 1 indexed, ranging from 1-31